# Foreign key not getting correctly set (coming as null)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Consider two tables TableA and TableB:

```
class TableA
    has_many: TableBs
end

class TableB
    has_many: TableAs
end
```

In controller of TableB:

```
class TableBController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @tableB = TableB.new
    end

    def create
        @tableB = TableB.new(tableB_params)
        @tableB.save
    end

    def tableB_params
        params.require(:tableB).permit(:tableAId, :date, :time)
    end
end
```

tableAId above is the connection between TableB and TableA.
I have some doubts:

1. Is this a foreign key constraint? I couldn't find any material online which says that a has_many attribute creates a foreign key, although the migration file suggests so.
2. On creating an instance of TableB, I've no idea why the value of tableAId is set as null. This creation is done via a form_for construct in new.html.erb in app\views\tableBs. The date and time values are set correctly. I'm using the same method in the new.html.erb file for tableAId, date, and time columns. I'm viewing these values in the rails console. Database is sqlite3.

Thanks in advance.

ADDENDUM:
Migrations seem to be correctly set:

```
class AddTableAToTableB < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :tableBs, :tableA, index: true
    add_foreign_key :tableBs, :tableAs
  end
end
```

**[EDIT]**
As per @ilan berci's answer below, I edited TableB like so:

```
class TableB
    has_many: TableAs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for    :tableAs
end
```

Still TableB's :tableAId attribute is set as null. For completeness, I'm also including the relevant form field that selects a name from TableA from a dropdown:

```
<%= f.label :tableA_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :tableA_id, TableA.all, :id,
                            :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

So from the above dropdown, I correctly see the list of TableA's instances, but on submitting the form, the tableA_id is still null.

Comment: your TableA and TableB have many to many relationship. You need to define a middle table too to manage many to many relationship among them.

Comment: @SachinR, is this a mandatory requirement? I mean, can't two tables related by has_many attributes on both sides function without an intermediate table?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is this a foreign key constraint? I couldn't find any material
>   online which says that a has_many attribute creates a foreign key,
>   although the migration file suggests so.

No, this is not a foreign key constraint.  This is an ActiveRecord construct which creates a lot of helper methods for you to navigate the relation.  If you want to add foreign keys, you have to do it yourself in your migration files

> 2) On creating an instance of TableB, I've no idea why the value of
>   tableAId is set as null. This creation is done via a form_for
>   construct in new.html.erb in app\views\tableBs. The date and time
>   values are set correctly. I'm using the same method in the
>   new.html.erb file for tableAId, date, and time columns. I'm viewing
>   these values in the rails console. Database is sqlite3.

If you wish to use nested forms then you must add "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in your model and follow the instructions on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
This method adds more methods that simplify creating and updating of the nested resource.

Comment: The link above is informative, but please see edit to my question as it didn't work.